# ActionBar Sherlock How to reset navigation mode to default value

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I`m using Action Bar sherlock where main activity has NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST.

```
    mLocations = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.locations);
    Context context = getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext();
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> list = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                context, R.array.locations, R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item);
    list.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);

    getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
    getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(list, this);
```

Each item from navigation list opens new activity. After pressing BACK button, you go back to main activity. The problem is, so that navigation list keeps previous choice.

For example navigation list has: Home, Menu 1, Menu 2
If you choose Manu 1, new activity appears. Then you press back, main activity displaed BUT navigation list has "Menu 1" selected. So its not possible to go to Menu 1 again. Need to select Home, than again Menu 1. How to fix it?

Please help.
thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that in the Home Activity, you can just set the menu item in the onResume event

```
 protected void onResume(final int actId) {
    super.onResume();

    getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(0);
}
```